# Find out which kernel source files were used when kernel was compiled

Tags: kernel, security, linux-kernel, compiling, source

I am compiling the Linux kernel for my specific hardware and I only select the drivers/options which I really need. This is in contrast to a typical distribution kernel, where they compile almost everything, to be compatible with as many hardware configurations as possible.

I imagine, for my kernel, I am only using 1% of the total kernel code (order of magnitude estimate).

**Is there any way to find out which files from the kernel source I have actually used when I build my kernel?**

This is not an academical question. Suppose I have compiled my kernel 3.18.1. Now a security update comes along, and 3.18.2 is released. I have learned in my [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190948/git-show-which-files-have-changed-between-kernel-3-18-6-and-3-18-7) how to find which files have change between releases. If I knew whether any of the files I am using have changed, I would recompile my kernel to the new version. If, on the other hand, the changes only affect files which I am not using anyway, I can keep my current kernel version.

Comment: I can't see an easy and reliable way to make this monitoring based on your screen output. However, you could use the `inotify` api and right before you hit enter on `make`, create a notification to log to a file or print to `STDOUT`
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163572/how-to-move-a-file-to-another-directory-as-soon-as-it-is-created-in-linux/ - is just a matter of monitoring what files are read during your build process :)

Comment: If there is a change in a file which you do not compile. How does it affect you. You can just run make to be safe, and see if make says "up-to-date" or is building some files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiling my comment as answer:

1. Run the following command on one shell. You can make a shell script of it or demonize with the `-d` option.

   ```
   inotifywait -m -r -e open --format '%f' /kernel_sources/directory/in_use/ -o /home/user/kernel_build.log
   ```
2. On other shell, execute `make`
3. The log file `/home/user/kernel_build.log` will have a list of the files that have been opened(read operation) during the build process.

Comment: this looks like this might work. I wonder though, whether there is no easier (more direct) way to do it.

Comment: You could use `find /home/ -atime +1` to see what files were acessed on the last 2 days for example, but i think inotify would be a more reliable way to get this info ;)

Comment: yes, but `atime` only works  if your filesystem supports it (is mounted with that option).

Comment: For sure. Since even the "purest" form of read still writes something to disc, like `cat /etc/fstab` will write on the file metadata information about when it was last acessed, mount points with `noatime` will cause you problems and, that's why i marked the find solution as not reliable :)